# How do I inherit the pixel value of width: auto?

Tags: css, inheritance, less

I have got this HTML and CSS structure:

HTML:

```
<div id="out">
   content
   <div id="in">
      content2
   </div>
</div
```

CSS:

```
#out {
   width: auto;
}

#in{
   width: inherit;
}
```

So I don't want `#in` to inherit the `width: inherit`, but the pixel amount that comes from `#out`.
Is this possible in CSS or in LESS?
If so, how?

Comment: why not `#in{ width: 100%; }` ?

Comment: can you be more precise ... as the #in will by default take all the width

Comment: @TemaniAfif, well could be different if for example it's an inline-block or similar.

Comment: @Johannes maybe, and we also need to consider the padding in this case as width may include them or not ... well the question is not clear

Comment: `#in {width: 100%}`

Comment: the spaces and the semicolon won't make a difference ...

Comment: Accidentally clicked Add comment, wasn't finished: i wanted to say that that styling worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the width of the inner div to be the same as the parent, use `width: 100%`

Tips:

- Don't specify the 'width: auto' in this case, as that's the default. (Only use if you need to overwrite another declaration.)
- If you use 'width: inherit' is uses the same **CSS** value as the parent - in
  this case, 'width: auto'. So it's actually also a waste of time writing that!